# find replace while keeping an argument using sed

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I have a tex file containing instances of a command of the form `\qdb{123}` where the 123 can be generalised to any number of any length. I need to convert these statements into something more complicated: such as `\text1{123}\text2{123}`. The idea is that the number within the brackets is being used many times within the new output.

I need a method outside of the tex `\newcommand` function (this will be a pre processing step). Is sed the right tool, and if so, then how?

Comment: Sed is a great tool for that. But, unless you spend a lot of effort for it, it will easily fail for cases like + linebreak in command + comments, etc. If you 'input' command is really that easy (no long text, no special cases), sed will do fine

Comment: The replace is to be relatively simple, no linebreaks and no comments.  If I could do this as a \newcommend it would be easy; but I can't in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple solution could look like:

input:

```
asldkfj aslfj ;aldfj \qdb{123} asdflk
% 
\qdb{452345} somecommand \texttt{asdf}
```

output:

```
asldkfj aslfj ;aldfj \text1{123}\text2{123} asdflk
% 
\text1{452345}\text2{452345} somecommand \texttt{asdf}
```

**by running (output to console, for testing):**

```
sed -e 's/\\qdb{\([0-9]*\)}/\\text1{\1}\\text2{\1}/g' test.txt
```

**by running (make changes directly on the file):**

```
sed -i -e 's/\\qdb{\([0-9]*\)}/\\text1{\1}\\text2{\1}/g' test.txt
```

adapt the `\\text1{\1}\\text2{\1}` to suite your needs. `\1` is the back-reference to the matched number.

needless to say: *make sure to have a backup!*

Comment: This works. I don't grasp the sed -i, I used sed -e and that was fine; but I had to output to a new file name. How can I simply rewrite over what I had?

Answer (score 0):

If ruby is available, then perhaps something like this:

```
prompt> irb
>> s = "lorem \\qdb{123} ipsum \\qdb{123} lorem"
=> "lorem \\qdb{123} ipsum \\qdb{123} lorem"
>> s.gsub /\\qdb\{(\d+)\}/m, '\text1{\1}\text2{\1}'
=> "lorem \\text1{123}\\text2{123} ipsum \\text1{123}\\text2{123} lorem"
>>
```

Backslash requires extra backslash escaping.

Comment: lots of backslashes, indeed ;)